# Sequelize-Oracle Only returns 100 rows even if limit is more than 100

Tags: node.js, database, oracle, sequelize.js

Has any one encountered the same question about sequelize-oracle or sequelize? My sequelize-rracle Only returns 100 rows even if limit is more than 100.

That is quite wired and I hope someone could help me. Thanks!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely the library you're using has a dependency on an older version of node-oracledb. In the past, the default for [oracledb.maxRows](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#propdbmaxrows) was 100. You could try setting that to an arbitrarily high number, just be sure you have enough memory in Node.js to handle the data returned from the query.

In later versions, the default value was changed to 0 and the code was updated to interpret that as unlimited.

Comment: Thx! Under your suggestion, I tried to execute raw sql through oracledb directly and the number of rows it returned was correct so the problem is in sequelize-oracle. Sequelize-oracle has a default option: {maxRows: 100 || options.maxRows} in the file node_modules/sequelize-oracle/lib/dialects/oracle/query.js, which is the option passed to oracledb to execute. Thanks a lot!! It is the maxRows affecting.